# Unable to load Serilog.Enrichers.CorrelationId, Version=3.0.1.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null since it is not strongly typed

Tags: serilog, strong-typing, serilog-sinks-file

I am trying to load Serilog from an assembly which is strongly typed and is in GAC. I am unable to load assembly Serilog.Enrichers.CorrelationId, Version=3.0.1.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null, since this is not strongly typed.

Error:

Could not load file or assembly 'Serilog.Enrichers.CorrelationId, Version=3.0.1.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null' or one of its dependencies. A strongly-named assembly is required. (Exception from HRESULT: 0x80131044)

Any help is appreciated!